# Deshabilitar los campos de escritura si el registro existe, en caso contrario que los habilite Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, apex, apex-chart

Les comento que estoy buscando la manera de que, se me deshabilite la escritura en los campos si el registro existe, así el usuario no debe poder editarlo. Y que se me habiliten si el registro no existe, para así poder ingresarlo.

[image]

Lo que hice fue crear una acción dinámica que al dar clic en el botón buscar, y si me encuentra los datos de coincidencia, que se me deshabiliten dichos campos P63_TIPO_IDENTIFICACACION,P63_NOMBRE,P63_APELLIDO, pero no me resulta.

Lo que quisiera saber es cómo deshabilitar la escritura en los campos si el registro existe y que se me habiliten si el registro no existe, para así poder ingresarlo. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

A continuación los pasos:

1. Crear la acción dinámica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Crear una acción de tipo Execute Server-side Code, por ejemplo:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muy importante incluir los elementos correspondientes en Items to submit, Items to return.

3. Crear una segunda acción para deshabilitar el elemento
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. Guardar los cambios y probar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por detallarme paso a paso la creación de esta acción dinámica.